# TLS_method() is returning <incomplete type> and couldn't see the ssl_method_st variables on gdb

Tags: c, ubuntu, ssl, openssl, gdb

```
ctx = InitCTX();
        /* Create the socket. The three arguments are:
         *          * 1) Internet domain
         *                   * 2) Stream Socket
         *                            * 3) Default Protocol (TCP in this case)
         *                                     * */
        clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        printf("\nCreated client socket = %d\n",clientSocket);

        /* Configure settings of the server address struct
         *          * Address Family = Internet
         *                   * Set port number , using htons() to use proper byte order
         *                            * Set IP add of remote server
         *                                     * Set al padding bits field to 0
         *                                              * */
        serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverAddr.sin_port = htons(443);
        serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(arg);
        memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr.sin_zero));


 addr_size = sizeof(serverAddr);
        if ((connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, addr_size)) == 0) {

                ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
                SSL_set_fd(ssl, clientSocket);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
```

this is my InitCTX() definition:

```
SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{   SSL_METHOD *method = NULL;
    SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
    method = TLS_method();
    printf("\n method: %d", method);
    /* method = TLSv1_2_client_method();  * Create new client-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}
```

Below is the debug output from gdb:

```
Thread 1 "client" hit Breakpoint 1, InitCTX () at mockclient_util.c:30
30  {   SSL_METHOD *method = NULL;
(gdb) s
[New Thread 0x7fffeeffd640 (LWP 21600)]
31      SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
(gdb) 
[New Thread 0x7fffee7fc640 (LWP 21601)]
32      method = TLS_method(); 
(gdb) 
33      printf("\n method: %d", method);
(gdb) p method
$1 = (SSL_METHOD *) 0x7ffff7f9c2c0
(gdb) ptype method
type = struct ssl_method_st {
    <incomplete type>
}
(gdb) s
__printf (format=0x555555567860 "\n method: %d") at ./stdio-common/printf.c:28
28  ./stdio-common/printf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) fin
Run till exit from #0  __printf (format=0x555555567860 "\n method: %d") at ./stdio-common/printf.c:28
Input IP = xx.xx.xx.xx
InitCTX () at mockclient_util.c:35
35      ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */
Value returned is $2 = 20
(gdb) p ctx
$3 = (SSL_CTX *) 0x0
(gdb) ptype ctx
type = struct ssl_ctx_st {
    <incomplete type>
}
(gdb)
```

- I was getting a SEGFAULT at SSL_new() and when I checked 'ctx' on gdb it was  (it should have described the structure) followed by 'method' which also showed  returned form TLS_method()

Also on printing  p method: (SSL_METHOD *) 0x7ffff7f9c2c0
and p ctx: (SSL_CTX *) 0x555555582c70
and p * ctx:
$6 = incomplete type
and p * method:
$7 = incomplete type

gives the adjacent outputs^^

However and method are not NULL, I have checked with NULL checks, this tell TLS_method is not returning NULL for sure, but why is it incomplete struct

Comment: Where is the struct definition of `ssl_method_st`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The likely reason is that the library creators did not want you to look into the data types or even rely on some specific layout. As your client application is only supposed to hold a pointer, it does not need to know the internals. The library functions will have the complete struct definition. That is not an error but intented behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

> why is it incomplete struct

Because the structure was forward declared, and its *definition* is not available.

Here is an example showing what's going on:

```
// foo.c
struct Foo {
  int x;
};

static struct Foo foo;

struct Foo *fn() { return &foo; }
```

```
// x.c
struct Foo;  // forward declaration
struct Foo *fn();
int main()
{
  struct Foo *foo = fn();
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -c foo.c && gcc -g x.c foo.o && gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1131: file x.c, line 5.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at x.c:5
5         struct Foo *foo = fn();
(gdb) n
6         return 0;
(gdb) p foo
$1 = (struct Foo *) 0x555555558014 <foo>
(gdb) p *foo
$2 = <incomplete type>
```

Note that `foo.c` was compiled *without* debug info (without `-g` flag).

If you build it with debug info, the picture changes:

```
gcc -g x.c foo.c && gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1131: file x.c, line 5.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at x.c:5
5         struct Foo *foo = fn();
(gdb) n
6         return 0;
(gdb) p foo
$1 = (struct Foo *) 0x555555558014 <foo>
(gdb) p *foo
$2 = {x = 0}    <<<=== definition of Foo is available in foo.c
```

Conclusion: you want to link against debug version of `libssl.a`, or if using `libssl.so`, you'll want to install debug info for it (provided by your distribution as a separate package).

Comment: My ubuntu 22.04 machine has OpenSSL 3.0.2 installed by default and I don't want to install any previous versions because of security issues. 
When I checked on installing debug info it goes with the installation and compilation of OpenSSL, but since mine is default from ubuntu, how do I install debug info for libssl.so.3 ??

Comment: @VikasGowdaLV Who said anything about installing _previous_ version? And surely you can figure out how to use your package manager yourself? `libssl.so.3` comes from the `libssl3:amd64` package, `apt search libssl3` shows that you want to install `libssl3-dbgsym`.

Comment: I am not able to install libssl3-dbgsym,, 
result for apt search says its installed,, 

```
$ apt search libssl3
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libssl3/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.12 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
``` 

,, result for apt-get istall libssl3-dbgsym says couldn't locate package :(

Comment: @VikasGowdaLV this page might help you: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages